# Why is it not working?

Tags: c++, if-statement, while-loop, compilation

I want to create a program that will transform the same words into one. I have a problem with code where I used "while". If I put "if" instead of "while" its working, but not as right as I want, so I need to use "while", but its not working correctly. Its compiling, but not working after inputting the string a.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main ( ) {
    string a;
    cout << "Введите string a: ";
    getline(cin,a);
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++) {
        while (a[i]=a[i+1]) {
            for (int z = i; z < a.length(); z++) {
                a[z]=a[z+1];
            }
        }
    }
    cout << endl << a << endl;
}
```

Comment: Please edit this to show provided input string and expected output.  Also, what happens when you single step though this in a debugger?  That can often show you where the mistakes are in your code.

Comment: Instead of the for loop, how about a.erase(a.begin() + i)  http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/erase/

Comment: `while (a[i]=a[i+1])` - Did you intend *assignment* there? Are you *sure* you didn't mean `while (a[i]==a[i+1])`

Comment: How are you using `getline` without the string header?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it!

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main ( ) {
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"Russian");
    cout << "Сборник задач: 7.2" << "\nLv Easy" << "\nExercise #02" << endl << endl;
    string a;
    cout << "Enter a line: ";
    getline(cin,a);
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < a.length(); j++) {
            if (a[i]==a[i+1]) {
                for (int z = i; z < a.length(); z++)
                    a[z]=a[z+1]; } } }
    cout << endl << a << endl << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 while (a[i]=a[i+1]) {
```

you probably mean

```
while (a[i]==a[i+1]) {
```

`=` is assignment; `==` is comparison.

When compilomg, pass `-Wall` to get warnings about this sort of thing.  (If a microsoft compiler turning warnings on may require something different; for other compilers, `-Wall` means "turn on warnings: all normal ones").

Answer (score 0):

Even when I replaced `while` with `if` it still wasn't working as you intended. I'm more surprised that you're able to use `getline` without the string header. You're also assigning the previous character of string `a` to the next character of `a`.

Please try this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<string>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<string> dupes;
    string word;
    string a;
    cout<<"Enter line:";
    getline(cin , a);
    int i = 0; //the counter
    while(i <= a.length()) {
       if(!isspace(a[i])) {
            word += a[i];
       } if(isspace(a[i])) {
           bool present = (find(dupes.begin() , dupes.end() , word) != dupes.end());
            if(!present) {
                dupes.push_back(word);
                word = "";
            }
            word = "";
       }
       ++i;
    }
}
```

Try your best to avoid nesting loops into one another when possible.